# Multiple inputs with array names

Tags: php, html

I have a form with 5 input fields. Each field has an array name, because there is possiblity of more than one record creation at once.

**Example:**

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
<input type="text" name="surname[]" />
<input type="text" name="address[]" />
<input type="text" name="phone[]" />
<input type="text" name="age[]" />
```

My question is how to manage multiple name arrays with php? I know how to do it with single array (multiple checkboxes checked case), but i got stuck here.

```
$all[] = $_POST["name"];
$all[] = $_POST["surname"];
$all[] = $_POST["address"];
$all[] = $_POST["phone"];
$all[] = $_POST["age"];
???

foreach {....???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each input will have an index and, by multiplying all the values, all fields within same group will have same array index:

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $num => $one){

    echo $_POST['name'][$num]; // or $one
    echo $_POST['surname'][$num];
    echo $_POST['address'][$num];
    echo $_POST['phone'][$num];
    echo $_POST['age'][$num];
}
```

Comment: you would need to check if that index is set for other fields other than name[](surname,address etc) else you would get an undefined error, if the field isn't set.

Comment: One more question. Only first can be called with variable $one? All others should be called using $_POST, right?

Comment: @sweettea i have validation / all fields are required anyways :)

Comment: yes, only first because that is the array I started with, but you can use `$num` for all ..

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$all = $_POST["name"];
foreach($all as $val) {
    //Do whatever with $val
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's probably best to use multidimensional arrays like so:

```
$all['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$all['surname'] = $_POST['surname'];
$all['address'] = $_POST['address'];
$all['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
$all['age'] = $_POST['age'];

//1st processing option
foreach ($all as $key => $dataList) {
    //some code
    foreach ($dataList as $data) {
        //some code
    }
}

//2nd processing option
foreach ($all['name'] as $data) {
    //some code
}
//repeat for each of 'name, surname, address, phone, age'
```